# Pseudo inverse operation of matrix

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $h_{i} \in \mathbb{C}^{1\times M}$ and $M$ is a postive constant. $H \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times M}$ is a matrix including $K$ vectors, i.e. $H = [h_{1}^{T},...,h_{K}^{T}]^{T}$, $K<M$. Let $W$ represent the right inverse matrix of $H$ and is formulated as $H^*(HH^*)^{-1}$. $*$ indicates the conjugate transpose. Colunm vectors are used to experss $W$ as $[w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{K}]$.

Question: Determining the two norm of column vector in $W$, i.e. $ \left\|w_{i}\right\|^{2} $.

I calculated that as:

$ \left\|w_{i}\right\|^{2} $

$= w_{i}*w_{i}^{*}$

$= [(H^*(HH^*)^{-1})(H^*(HH^*)^{-1})^*]_{i,i}$

$= [(H^*(H^*)^{-1}H^{-1})(((HH^*)^{-1})^{*}H)]_{i,i}$

$= [H^{-1}((HH^*)^{-1})H)]_{i,i}$

$= [H^{-1}((H^*)^{-1}H^{-1}H)]_{i,i}$

$= [H^{-1}(H^*)^{-1}]_{i,i}$

$= [(H^*H)^{-1}]_{i,i}$

However, the answer is $[(HH^*)^{-1}]_{i,i}$. I think there must be something wrong with the calculation, which I can't find. I want to know what is the correct calculation process.

Comment: Your derivation doesn't make sense. $\|w_i\|^2$ is the scalar $w_i^\ast w_i$, not the $M\times M$ matrix $w_iw_i^\ast$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a $*$ between lines 4 and 5:

$= [(H^*(H^*)^{-1}H^{-1})(((HH^*)^{-1})^{*}H)]_{i,i}$

$= [H^{-1}((HH^*)^{-1})^*H)]_{i,i}$

Expand the inverse first, and then transpose.

You also need to use $(H^{-1})^*=(H^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and  help !  : ) 
I find the error in my derivation. As you shown, $ \left\|w_i\right\|^2 = w_i^**w_i $ rather than $w_i*w_i^*$. 

: )